# Azure B2C passport.js authorize url openid

Tags: javascript, azure, passport.js, openid-connect

I am having trouble using specific case there i need the first redirection url to microsoft when we try to login with our AD user.

login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=b2c_1_signin&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Flogin%2Fcallback&response_type=code%20id_token&response_mode=form_post&client_id=CLIENTID&state=tfdE5aeDSaOPro4u_B2KT2LcjSAF2IcW&nonce=wM8hmBYROUquHNYoS3NliX-1zCla5XwI&scope=offline_access%20openid&x-client-SKU=passport-azure-ad&x-client-Ver=4.0.0

How can i extract this URL from passport method instead of redirecting me into it ?
I can't see anything in the logs

```html
passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect', {
        failureRedirect: '/failure',
        session: false,
      }, () => {
        console.log(arguments);
      })(req, res, next);
```